# `moduleNameMapper` settings in jest.config.js doesn't work on CircleCI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, circleci

I have tested with my React-app in typescript, using ts-jest like below.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as renderer from "react-test-renderer";

import { ChartTitle } from "Components/chart_title";

describe("Component: ChartTitle", () => {
  it("will be rendered with no error", () => {
    const chartTitle = "My Chart 1";
    renderer.create(<ChartTitle title={chartTitle} />);
  });
});
```

and it has passed in my local environment but failed in CircleCI.

```sh
 FAIL  __tests__/components/chart_title.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeScript diagnostics (customize using `[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics` option):
    __tests__/components/chart_title.tsx:4:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'Components/chart_title'.

    4 import { ChartTitle } from "Components/chart_title";                              
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This `Components/` is an alias expression by `moduleNameMapper`, and I think it doesn't work in only CircleCI.

`jest --showConfig` option tells me there is no difference between local and CI environment.

Is there any fault in my settings?

### app/frontend/jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsConfig: "tsconfig.json",
      diagnostics: true
    },
    NODE_ENV: "test"
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^Components/(.+)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/$1"
  },
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", 'src'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  verbose: true
};
```

### app/frontend/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "types": ["jest"]
  },
  "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
  "paths": {
    "Components/*": ["src/components/*"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "__tests__"]
}
```

### app/frontend/package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build-production": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode production",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "npx eslint src/**/* __tests__/**/* --ext \".ts, .tsx\"",
  },
}
```

### app/.circleci/.config.yml

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    ...
    steps:
      - run:
        name: run tests for frontend
        command: npm test -- -u
        working_directory: frontend
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`tsconfig-paths-jest` is not usable in Jest >23. For current Jest 26 I got it working via:  https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping/

`jest.config.js`

```
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig');

module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>/src/' } )
};
```

`tsconfig.json` "compilerOptions"

```
 "baseUrl": "./src",
 "paths": {            
  "@models/*": [ "./models/*" ],
  "@inputs/*": [ "./inputs/*" ],
  "@tests/*": [ "./__tests__/*" ],
  "@resolvers/*": [ "./resolvers/*" ],
  "@seeds/*": [ "./seeds/*" ],
  "@index": [ "./index.ts" ],
  "@ormconfig":[ "../ormconfig.ts" ]
  },
```

Comment: Thanks! This should be the correct answer!

Comment: combing the internet, this is one of the best solutions I have found. Great Work, thanks

Comment: Was missing the `{ prefix: '<rootDir>/src/' }` part myself. Thanks!

Comment: Updated link: https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping

Comment: THANKS for this. I looked into numerous SO threads, blogs, etc, and none had this complete - the `pathsToModuleNameMapper` second parameter, the options object with the prefix, was exactly what I was missing. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 9):

I've finally found out its solution.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/138), I use `tsconfig-paths` and `tsconfig-paths-jest`.

So my setting-files have changed like below.

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "paths": {
      "Components/*": ["src/components/*"]
    }
  },
  "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "__tests__"]
}
```

#### jest.config.js

```
/* eslint-disable import/order */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const tsconfig = require("./tsconfig.json");
const moduleNameMapper = require("tsconfig-paths-jest")(tsconfig);

module.exports = {
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsConfig: "tsconfig.json",
      diagnostics: true
    },
    NODE_ENV: "test"
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [`${__dirname}/src/setupTests.ts`],
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", 'src'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  verbose: true,
  moduleNameMapper
};
```

And my tests worked well in CircleCI, but I still have no idea why these tests 
had worked in my local before this solution.